# What was in Rama Kandra's luggage?

Tags: the-matrix

In the movie *The Matrix Revolutions*, Rama Kandra carries a luggage with him in the Mobil Avenue as he gets on the train to see his daughter off to the Matrix.

Why would a program need a luggage? Libraries to use in case of need?

Comment: Luggage is just a word, like Karma

Comment: Do not try and understand the luggage. That's impossible. Instead... only try to realize the truth: there is no luggage

Comment: I've sent a twit to the actor. It's possible he was told.

Comment: @Valorum he was told what?

Comment: @C.Koca - It's possible he was told what was in his luggage in-universe. It might also be interesting to learn what was *actually* in the luggage.

Answer (score 4):

The luggage could signify bits and pieces of his current life, which he wished to carry forward with him.

That could include:

- **Memories**: Literally and figuratively. All programs have a stack, a private memory set.
- **Context**: Programs have a semblance of what they are currently doing. Could be representing that.

There are a bunch of other things, but that would end up being a lecture on how processes are managed inside the kernel, so I'm going to spare you all from going through that!

Comment: This seems like aimless guessing to me. Do you have any evidence to back this up?

Comment: @Valorum - There is literally not a single line of dialogue even mentioning the luggage. What else do we have at this point? It's a bit harsh to call it "aimless guessing".

Comment: Well, I've contacted (via email) the films art directors, the set dresser and the actors involved in the filming of that scene to see if they can offer any insight. Hopefully one/all will respond

Comment: I could have just as easily posted an answer that says ***"probably it's clothes"*** but then my answer would be just as much of a guess as yours, and with just as little justification

Comment: @Valorum - Was my answer really that bad? I did write it in the maximum possible context, and it was definitely not as facile as "probably its clothes". Hope so your email gets a response, but that does NOT make my answer "aimless guessing". It was the best possible explanation given the existing resources. The matrix does involves heavy symbolism, and especially to computing and programming. Given that, my answer was definitely way better than "probably its clothes".

Comment: Your answer is certainly *cleverer* than "It's clothes" but that's about it. Also, are you saying that Rama lost a lifetime of memories when he lost his bag?

Comment: @Valorum If you read the question, the OP asks "Why would a program need luggage" and my answer specifically addresses that. OP also mentioned "Libraries", meaning that OP was indeed looking for an answer that provided technical analogies. My answer is accurate on both counts, and covers EXACTLY what the OP asked.
Please do tell me, how my answer is aimless guessing in this context?

Comment: Because you're not basing it on anything. Do we see any other programs carrying external memory devices?

Comment: @Valorum When a question is not directly answerable, we usually make conjectures from real world, for things like how many soldiers operate a longboat. While Stark's answer is obviously not what I was looking after, I see no reason to criticise it.

Comment: @C.Koca - Do we see any other programs toting around spare memory?

Comment: @Valorum - When Agent Smith captures Neo the first time, he opens a FOLDER containing FILES on Mr Anderson. Doesn't get any more literal than that! We see that their communication device with the outside world manifests as a literal telephone, which is not a cell phone, but a public pay phone which accurately mirrors how sockets in the TCP/IP stack are. While not directly memory, this is sufficient evidence that The Matrix does use visual analogs to computing terms in the film. I will certainly get back to you with more instances of this.

Comment: @Stark07 - It sounds like you're reaching. The file the Smith shows Neo is clearly intended as an interrogation tool. I wouldn't be surprised (under the circumstance) if it hadn't been generated specifically for the event.

Answer (score -1):

When we first see Rama Kandra he's wearing an ugly sweater-vest. When we encounter him again a few hours later, he's wearing a tan jacket and trousers. As this demonstrates that programs like him have the capacity to change their clothing, the most obvious thing for his luggage to contain is *changes of clothing.*

[image]

Since Rama and his wife aren't intending to stay with Sati after dropping her off with the Oracle...

> **Neo:** *Goodbye? You’re not staying with her?*
>
> **Rama-Kandra:** *It is not possible. Our arrangement with the Frenchman was for our daughter only. My wife and I must return to our world.*

... it seems more likely than not that all three sets of luggage would contain ***changes of clothing for Sati*** rather than anything for the two parents (who seem to be returning home the same day).

Comment: Well, this theory ignores the residual self images in Matrix completely.

Comment: I am not talking about RSI of the luggage. Their clothing changes probably due to the changes in their RSI. So guessing they might luggages is mediocre at best.

Comment: @C.Koca - I agree. Actual "luggage" would only be used by the humans trapped in the matrix. The programs themselves can see past such abstractions, and have no use for those.